# How can I set up a 'Data Layer' variable to pass a 'Unique ID' back to our partners when a conversion occurs?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Currently we use GTM to house all of our partners conversion pixels that fire on our success page. We're trying to create a 'Data Layer' variable that we can add to our partners conversion pixels that will then send a 'Unique Conversion ID' back to the respective partner each time the conversion pixel fires. This will allow us to cross check our conversion data against our partners.

How can we accomplish this?

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `dataLayer.push(object)` and it will trigger an event called Message and it will put in the dataLayer what you want.